# Definir si un punto (coordenada geográfica) se encuentra en un área del mapa

Tags: php, map, gps

Tengo un servicio que obtiene la latitud y longitud que un dispositivo GPS me envía. 
Ademas tengo una base de datos en JSON con zonas (id, nombre, latitud del centro, longitud del centro y radio), quiero retornar en que zona se encuentra el dispositivo, para lograrlo recordé matemática básica de secundaria:

```
  function check($pXp, $pYp, $pXc, $pYc, $pRc)
{
 $result=false;
 $x = pow(abs($pXp-$pXc),2);
 $y = pow(abs($pYp-$pYc),2);
 $total = sqrt($x+$y);
 if($total<=$pRc){$result=true;} //Menor o igual
 return $result;
}
```

Pero me di cuenta que estoy mezclando conceptos básicos. Estoy intentando usar una formula para planos y coordenadas geográficas decimales.

Desconozco la medida del radio de las áreas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede realizar con esa fórmula ya que la tierra no es plana. Debes utilizar la fórmula de Havernise para obtener la distancia entre dos puntos, en tu caso entre el dado y el origen (que sería el radio).

[image: Fórmula de Havernise para el radio]

Siendo r el radio de la Tierra. λ2 la longitud del GPS, λ1 la longitud del centro, Φ2 la latitud del GPS y Φ1 la latitud del centro. Las latitudes y longitudes expresadas en radianes, supongo que te la darán en grados. La distancia la obtendrás en metros. Con esta fórmula obtendrías la distancia entre el origen y el punto, que es lo que estabas intentando conseguir para hacer la comparación.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente he usado esa formula, copiando el siguiente código http://assemblysys.com/es/calculo-de-la-distancia-en-funcion-de-la-latitud-y-longitud-en-php/

Answer (score 0):

Por completar la [respuesta de Adrián](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155511/7478) adjunto una implementación en `PHP`de esta fórmula, se trata de una función que recibe latitud y longitud de ambos puntos junto con qué unidades se quiere la respuesta y la precisión decimal:

```
   <?php
        function distanceCalculation($point1_lat, $point1_long, $point2_lat, $point2_long, $unit = 'km', $decimals = 2) {
            // Cálculo de la distancia en grados
            $degrees = rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($point1_lat))*sin(deg2rad($point2_lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($point1_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point2_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point1_long-$point2_long)))));

            // Conversión de la distancia en grados a la unidad escogida (kilómetros, millas o millas naúticas)
            switch($unit) {
                case 'km':
                    $distance = $degrees * 111.13384; // 1 grado = 111.13384 km, basándose en el diametro promedio de la Tierra (12.735 km)
                    break;
                case 'mi':
                    $distance = $degrees * 69.05482; // 1 grado = 69.05482 millas, basándose en el diametro promedio de la Tierra (7.913,1 millas)
                    break;
                case 'nmi':
                    $distance =  $degrees * 59.97662; // 1 grado = 59.97662 millas naúticas, basándose en el diametro promedio de la Tierra (6,876.3 millas naúticas)
            }
            return round($distance, $decimals);
        }

            $point1 = array("lat" => "48.8666667", "long" => "2.3333333"); // París (Francia)
            $point2 = array("lat" => "19.4341667", "long" => "-99.1386111"); // Ciudad de México (México)
            $km = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']); // Calcular la distancia en kilómetros (por defecto)
            $mi = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long'], 'mi'); // Calcular la distancia en millas
            $nmi = distanceCalculation($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long'], 'nmi'); // Calcular la distancia en millas naúticas
            echo "La distancia entre París (Francia) y la Ciudad de México (México) es de $km km (= $mi millas = $nmi millas naúticas)";
        ?>
```

**FUENTE:** [Aquí](http://assemblysys.com/es/calculo-de-la-distancia-en-funcion-de-la-latitud-y-longitud-en-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Justamente así lo hacía yo hasta que descubrí otra manera! Utiliza mejor otro logaritmo:

```
        $coorPuntoAy;
        $coorPuntoAx;
        $coorPuntoBy;
        $coorPuntoBx;

        $RadianPuntoAy=($coorPuntoAy*pi())/180;
        $RadianPuntoAx=($coorPuntoAx*pi())/180;
        $RadianPuntoBy=($coorPuntoBy*pi())/180;
        $RadianPuntoBx=($coorPuntoBx*pi())/180;

        $RADIOTIERRA= 6371;

        $distancia = acos(sin($RadianPuntoAy)*sin($RadianPuntoBy) + cos($RadianPuntoAy) * cos($RadianPuntoBy) * cos ($RadianPuntoAx-$RadianPuntoBx)) * $RADIOTIERRA;
```