# Crear un array que cumpla ciertas condiciones en PHP

Tags: php

Tenemos una base de datos con talleres y sus coordenadas. Una vez pasados los datos a un array, medimos la distancia desde el punto de localización introducido en un mapa (o por geolocation) y los talleres más cercanos.

Hago un foreach para recoger las coordenadas de cada taller, tal y como se muestra en la imagen, y necesito recoger en otro array únicamente los talleres cuya distancia sea inferior, para pasarlos luego por JSON.

El problema es que al hacer:

```
if (distancia_a $distancia) { 
  array_push($data, $resultado); 
}
```

sólo me recoge el primer taller e ignora el resto.

¿Podríais echarme una mano?

```
    $coorYLocat=$coords['lat'];
    $coorXLocat=$coords['lng'];

    $RadYLocat=($coorYLocat*pi())/180;
    $RadXLocat=($coorXLocat*pi())/180;

    }
    $stmt->execute();
    // $stmt->debugDumpParams();
    $data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $RADIOTIERRA = '6371';
    $i=0;

    foreach ($data as $taller => $resultado);
    {

        $coorYTaller=$resultado['coordinate_y'];
        $coorXTaller=$resultado['coordinate_x'];

        $RadYTaller=($coorYTaller*pi())/180;
        $RadXTaller=($coorXTaller*pi())/180;
        $distance_a = acos(sin($RadYLocat)*sin($RadYTaller) + cos($RadYLocat) * cos($RadYTaller) * cos ($RadXLocat-$RadXTaller)) * $RADIOTIERRA;

        if ($distance_a <= $distance)
        {
            array_push($datos, $resultado);
        }
    }

echo json_encode($datos);
```

Comment: ¿qué es `$distance`?

Comment: $distance es la distancia que el usuario introduce en la página html mediante un slide.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución y la comparto por si alguien tiene más problemas como éste. He dejado el foreach de lado y he usado un for.

```
$distance=x //Distancia introducida por el usuario mediante un slide en HTML
$coorYLocat=$coords['lat'];
$coorXLocat=$coords['lng'];

$RadYLocat=($coorYLocat*pi())/180;
$RadXLocat=($coorXLocat*pi())/180;

}
$stmt->execute();
// $stmt->debugDumpParams();
$data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$RADIOTIERRA = '6371';
$resultado=array();

for ($i=0; $i<=(count($data)-1); $i++)
{
    $coorYTaller=$data[$i]['coordinate_y'];
    $coorXTaller=$data[$i]['coordinate_x'];

    $RadYTaller=($coorYTaller*pi())/180;
    $RadXTaller=($coorXTaller*pi())/180;

    $distance_a = acos(sin($RadYLocat)*sin($RadYTaller) + cos($RadYLocat) * cos($RadYTaller) * cos ($RadXLocat-$RadXTaller)) * $RADIOTIERRA;

    if ($distance_a <= $distance)
    {
        array_push($resultado,$i);
    }
}

echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este link a ver si te puede ayudar:

[Definir si un punto (coordenada geográfica) se encuentra en un área del mapa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155276/definir-si-un-punto-coordenada-geogr%C3%A1fica-se-encuentra-en-un-%C3%A1rea-del-mapa)

Comment: No, la localización y la medición están bien, lo que necesito es guardar los datos de dichos talleres que cumplen la condición, en un array. Pero no sé crear el array de forma que me recoja todos y cada uno de los que cumplen la condición, pues sólo me recoge el primero.

Comment: puedes probar a hacer $datos[]=$resultado en lugar del array_push, que creo recordar que necesitaba que el array ya tuviese algun elemento.

Comment: No, no me es válido. Y creo que ya he probado de todo xD

Comment: y que es distancia_a? en esto: if (distancia_a $distancia)